# Updating through SqlDataAdapter and DataSet in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, dataadapter

I have the fol code

```
 string user = "new user";
 DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
        string sql = string.Format("Select Counter,Occupants From Rooms where Room = '{0}'",room);
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        dAdapt.Fill(myDS, "Rooms");

        foreach (DataTable dt in myDS.Tables)
        {
            int var =(int) dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
            var--;
            dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0] = var;
            String occups = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            occups += user;
            dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1] = occups;
        }
        dAdapt.Update(myDS,"Rooms");
```

I'm retrieving a single row with two columns-- Counter(small int type) and Occupants(text type). I get an error saying that **the data types text and var char are incompatible in the equal to operator** But the error is pointed to the line `dAdapt.Fill(myDS, "Rooms");` which is weird. What's wrong here? And I'm pretty sure that the db connection is open as I've checked it by printing the connection status.

Comment: This won't work anyway unless you have specified an `Update-Command` for the `DataAdaper`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you show me how?

Comment: What is the type of Room, it seems, that it has text type too, and that's why the select dies on .Fill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your select, because you can use the syntax, that `Room = 'something'`, because text is not compatible with =.

Use `LIKE` instead of equal sign `(=)`.

Fixed query should look like:

```
SELECT Counter,Occupants FROM Rooms WHERE Room LIKE '{0}'
```

But I recommand to use `SqlParameters` instead of `string.Format`, because it is not secure.

Comment: Thanks! But still the change is not updated in the database. What should i do additionally? dAdapt.update() is not enough??

Comment: In this second problem, Tim Schmelter's answer could help you a lot, even he used the proper way with Sqlparameters. I think you should take a look on that answer too!

Answer (score 1):

This won't work anyway unless you have specified an Update-Command for the `DataAdaper`.

I would not load the record into memory to update it. Meanwhile it could have been changed from another transaction. It's inefficient anyway. Instead i would use a single update-command:

```
string updateSql = @"
    UPDATE ROOMS SET
        Counter = Counter + 1,
        Occupants = Occupants + ',' + @newUser
    WHERE
        Room = @Room";

using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSql, con))
{
    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newUser", user);
    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Room", room);
    con.Open();
    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I've followed your code but i get an error saying "text and varchar are incompatible in the add operator" and i guess the error is referring to the update command.

Comment: Make a habit of changing your code to use varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) instead of text and ntext, not only is it easier to use but text and ntext have been deprecated. You need to use the [UPDATETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx), [TEXTPTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176068.aspx) functions.